# wp_register_script not loading scripts

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

```js
function enqueue_my_so_scripts() {

 wp_register_script('theme-custom-js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/custom.js', array(), '', false );
 wp_register_script('theme-bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '3.3.7', true );

 wp_enqueue_script('theme-custom-js');
 wp_enqueue_script('theme-bootstrap-js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_so_scripts' );
```

I am not sure why scripts not loading any idea ...!!

Comment: Your code is fine. Make sure that actual js files are in the right folder and that they are accessible.

Comment: yes I have checked couple of time the file location but I think there must be something else which becoming a trouble.

Comment: Does the console show any error?

Comment: I am not sure but I am working on live domain http://creative.advertania.com/ can you please check as I have used javascript in custom.js for navbar shrink and its not working like this example"http://callmenick.com/_development/resize-header-on-scroll/"

Comment: Change this `(window).scroll` code to this `$(window).scroll`

Comment: I just changed and added "$" but still not working and I found this in console "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function at custom.js:2"

Comment: Wrap the code from `custom.js` file into an anonymous jQuery function. `(function($) { YOUR CODE HERE })(jQuery);`

Answer (score 0):

I checked your domain http://creative.advertania.com/ and I can see both the scripts custom.js and bootstrap.min.js are loading in footer.

If you are still not seeing the scripts, there might be cache issue at your end. Try clearing the cache and loading your domain name in other browser.

Comment: If its my cache problem so you must have resulted as working.. Actually I tried all the known options but trust me this is something I am unable to resolve.